# lib(128):capi_rsa_priv_enc:function not supported, errno 0

Tags: apache, curl, openssl, x509certificate

My scripts to sign file via api was working properly fine when my previous server setup was Ubuntu 20.04 and openssl version is 1.1.1b.

But after upgrade. i am getting this issue. Client environment is same before and after the server upgrade.

Now
Current Server Env :

```
    Ubuntu 22..04  
    Openssl 3.0.2  
    Apache 2.4.52  
    SSL x509 certificate is installed on the Apache Server
```

Client Env:

```
    Windows 2016  
    Curl 7.78.0
    openssl 1.1.1f
```

Below command has been executed to sign a file via web api running on Server over https.

curl.exe --request POST --cacert "ca.crt" --cert "user.crt" --engine capi --key-type ENG --key "user.key" --verbose -L "https://webapi:port" --header "content-type: multipart/form-data" --form "file=@file.txt" --output "out_file.txt"

### tailed output:

...
..

[5 bytes data]

- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Hello request (0):
  { [4 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
  } [232 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
  { [117 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
  { [1319 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
  { [556 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
  { [1979 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
  { [4 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
  } [4292 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
  } [37 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, internal error (592):
  } [2 bytes data]
- OpenSSL SSL_read: error:8006F074:lib(128):capi_rsa_priv_enc:function not supported, errno 0
  0 82.4M    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
- Closing connection 0
  curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: error:8006F074:lib(128):capi_rsa_priv_enc:function not supported, errno 0

As per some online resources it tried to disable tlsv1.2 and or tlsv1.3 on server ssl.conf but still issue remains the same.

My understanding on openssl and x509 certificate troubleshooting is limited .  Kindly help.

Comment: HI All, Can anyone help in solving this problem or provide any workaround